# openrave ros connection

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to ask about your opinion, I want to make a new motion planner to pa10 in openrave that use the concept of stocastic trajectory optimization , but I have the service of vision and camara in ros, it's posible to comunicate the vision on ros with the planner in pa10 over openrave and how?, or it's better make the planner in opml with the model of pa10 in rviz and how?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32673/openrave-ros-connection/) by [SD zaid issa](https://answers.ros.org/users/2233/sd-zaid-issa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-04-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

we frequently use openrave planning through the ROS network. please check out the armplanning_openrave.py script in the [orrosplanning](http://www.ros.org/wiki/orrosplanning) package; it offers a ros service for planning.

---

Originally posted by [Rosen Diankov](https://answers.ros.org/users/104/rosen-diankov/) with karma: 516 on 2012-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0